# sum a range of cells that are calculating total hours always returns 0

Tags: excel, sum

I have tried a bunch of things suggested in other posts on here where people have had issue where a range of cells aren't being treated as a number with no luck. The range of cells are formatted as numbers but when I test it with ISNUMBER it returns false. I have tried recreating in new cells, find/replace etc with no luck and i'm wondering if the source of my issue is the fact that data in these cells are hours, hoping somebody can tell where I am going wrong.

The column I am looking to sum contains the following formula in each cell:

=IFERROR(TEXT(U3-T3, "h"),"Invalid")

It is returning the difference in time between in this case T3 and U3. In this case U3 is 15:00 and T3 is 7:00 so it returns 8 in V3 where the above formula is located, which is exactly what I need it to do. But there is a whole column of cells that do this and what I want is to be able to return the total hours in that column, but when I try to sum the column it returns 0 and ISNUMBER returns as false, so I know its not treating the cell as a number, but what I can't figure out is why.

I'm sure I am probably overlooking something simply, but for the life of me I can't see what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `TEXT(U3-T3, "h")` turns the number into text and SUM ignores text.  Instead do: `=IFERROR(INT((U3-T3)*24)),"Invalid")`

Comment: That worked! Thanks man!